# How can I install Canon scanner/libpango

Tags: installation, pango

I am installing  Canon MG3650S printer/scanner on Ubuntu 22.04. It looks like something is wrong with installing libpango. I discovered that it was missing from the dependency list. However, after installing it, something is still missing. I noticed that "libpango-1.0-0 set to manually installed", but could not figure out what does it mean. Below you find the screen log.

```
~/Downloads/scangearmp2-3.20-1-deb$ sudo apt-get install libpango-1.0-0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
libpango-1.0-0 is already the newest version (1.50.6+ds-2).
libpango-1.0-0 set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 150 not upgraded.
~/Downloads/scangearmp2-3.20-1-deb$ sudo ./install.sh 
==================================================

ScanGear MP
Version 3.20
Copyright CANON INC. 2007-2015

==================================================
Command executed = sudo dpkg -iG ./packages/scangearmp2_3.20-1_amd64.deb
Selecting previously unselected package scangearmp2.
(Reading database ... 272630 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../scangearmp2_3.20-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking scangearmp2 (3.20-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of scangearmp2:
 scangearmp2 depends on libpango1.0-0 (>= 1.14.0); however:
  Package libpango1.0-0 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package scangearmp2 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 scangearmp2
Command executed = sudo dpkg -P scangearmp2
(Reading database ... 272652 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing scangearmp2 (3.20-1) ...
Purging configuration files for scangearmp2 (3.20-1) ...
```

BTW: On another copy of the same Ubuntu, I did not notice this issue. What could be the cause?

Answer (score 0):

You need the Package libpango1.0-0 - which can be install with Synaptic. That was my problem too. After that everything OK.
dpkg -L libpango1.0-0
dpkg -L libpango-1.0-0